# Given a list of lists in Python, return the maximum length uniquely-valued sublists

Tags: python, list, nested

I have the following list in Python:

```
l = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [2], [3], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [2], [5], [11], [2, 2], [3], [13], [2], [7], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2, 2], [17], [2], [3, 3], [19], [2, 2], [5]]
```

I want to write a function that will return the uniquely-valued sublists of maximum length. In this case, the function would return:

```
l = [[5], [7], [3, 3], [11], [13], [2, 2, 2, 2], [17], [19]]
```

I am still a beginner at python, and I have very little idea as to how to write such a function, however. The furthest I got was figuring out that I could iterate over the sublists by using nested loops. But from what I've seen of Python, it seems like there must be some simpler way to return the list I am looking for than using loops.

**Update:**

Here's what I was doing with the code: solving project euler #5, the non-brute force way!

I'm sure this code could be refactored, but whatever.

Thanks for your help, guys. `itemgetter` was just what I needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding = UTF-8

import argparse, sys, math
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args:
   intinput = int(sys.argv[1])
elif not sys.stdin.isatty():
    intinput = int(sys.stdin.read())
else:
    parser.print_help()

def prime_factorize(n):
    factors = []
    number = math.fabs(n)

    while number > 1:
        factor = get_next_prime_factor(number)
        factors.append(factor)
        number /= factor

    if n < -1: 
        factors[0] = -factors[0]

    return factors

def get_next_prime_factor(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2

    for x in range(3, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1), 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return x

    return int(n)


def mkfactors(n):
  tpf = []
  for i in range(n+1):
    tpf.extend(prime_factorize(i))
  return tpf

l = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(mkfactors(intinput))]

m = [max(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l,key=itemgetter(0)),key=itemgetter(0))]


prod = 1

for list in m:
  for element in list:
    prod *= element

print prod
```

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: Is it just me, or do I see prime numbers?

Comment: Please remove -ve votes, he has fixed his question and received a lot of good responses.

Comment: +1: This is a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[max(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l),key=itemgetter(0))]
```

*out:*

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that every sublist has the same elements, you can do:

```
l = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [2], [3], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [2], [5], [11], [2, 2], [3], [13], [2], [7], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2, 2], [17], [2], [3, 3], [19], [2, 2], [5]]

from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for ele in l:
    if len(my_dict[ele[0]]) < len(ele):
        my_dict[ele[0]] = ele
```

Result:

```
>>> my_dict.values()
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do here is to use a data structure that makes the problem simple, and then you can always convert back after the fact.

For example, a `dict` mapping keys (primes) to lengths (exponents) is easy. So:

```
>>> l = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [2], [3], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [2], [5], [11], [2, 2], [3], [13], [2], [7], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2, 2], [17], [2], [3, 3], [19], [2, 2], [5]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for sublist in l:
...     value, count = sublist[0], len(sublist)
...     if count > d.get(value, 0):
...         d[value] = count
>>> d
{2: 4, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1, 11: 1, 13: 1, 17: 1, 19: 1}
```

It should be obvious how to turn that back into a `list` of `list`s, so I'll leave that to you.

Note that this loses the order, but you can trivially fix that with `OrderedDict`. It also loses `list` identity—e.g., the `[2, 2, 2, 2]` that you get back at the end will be *equal to*, but not *the same as*, the original `[2, 2, 2, 2]`. But that's easy to fix too—just stored the `sublist` directly instead of using `count`. Anyway, I don't think either of these is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Note that you *don't* lose the order, because of the hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Marcin: Actually, you _do_ lose the order—you end up with _sorted_ order instead—because of the hashing algorithm. But either way, that's not something guaranteed by the language, it just happens to be true with this range of numbers with current CPython implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [2], [3], [7], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [2], [5], [11], [2, 2], [3], [13], [2], [7], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2, 2], [17], [2], [3, 3], [19], [2, 2], [5]]
l = [max(i for i in l if j in i) for j in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)]
print(l)
# [[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

I guess all it is is just a list comprehension with nested for loops, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

using `collections.Counter` and `sets`:

```
In [47]: s=set([x[0] for x in lis])

In [48]: c=[Counter(x) for x in lis]

In [49]: [max(c,key=lambda y:y[x]) for x in s]
Out[49]: 
[Counter({2: 4}),
 Counter({3: 2}),
 Counter({5: 1}),
 Counter({7: 1}),
 Counter({11: 1}),
 Counter({13: 1}),
 Counter({17: 1}),
 Counter({19: 1})]
```

Another way:

```
In [64]: from collections import defaultdict

In [65]: d=defaultdict(list)

In [66]: for x in lis:
    d[x[0]].append(len(x))
   ....:     

In [67]: [[x]*max(y) for x,y in d.items()]
Out[67]: [[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

Comment: @Marcin try to understand it then.

Comment: If this isn't supposed to be understood, it's not an answer.

Comment: Any non-trivial answer without an explanation of how it works isn't great - as it doesn't really help anyone in the long-run.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution would be to convert the sorted list to a dict with key as the first element of the list, which would eventually remove duplicates based on key.

```
>>> {e[0]: e for e in sorted(l)}.values()
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

for Python Version < 2.7 where dict comprehension is not available

```
>>> dict((e[0], e) for e in sorted(l)).values()
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

Comment: The rarely-used dict comprehension! Of course, this won't work in versions less than 2.7.

Comment: @Marcin: Off-course, you can always use the dict in build type to achieve the same result.